# Code crashes on c, most likely something to do with malloc?

Tags: c, memory, crash, malloc

this is quite basic but I've been trying to solve it for a few hours now with no success. This code is supposed to read 3 ints from user input and then, points according to the ints (n = how many, d = dimension, k is unrelated to this part) and create an array of them. For some reason it crashes on the second loop, where it fails to create the second point, but im not sure why. I think it might has something to do with malloc but I'm totally lost, would appreciate any help.

I inserted the input :

```
5 3 2 
1.2 3.4 0.1
```

2 times before it crashed.

Code is below:

```
int main(){

    double* pdata;
    int n,d,k;
    scanf("%d %d %d",&n,&d,&k );
    SPPoint*  parr [n];
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        double darr [d];
        for(int j = 0; j < d-1; j++)
        {
            scanf(" %lf", &darr[j]);
        }
        scanf(" %lf", &darr[d-1]);
    pdata = darr;
    parr[i] = spPointCreate(pdata, d, i); 
    }
}
```

This is the code for the spPointCreate function:

```
struct sp_point_t{
double* data;
int dim;
int index;
};

SPPoint* spPointCreate(double* data, int dim, int index){
SPPoint* point = malloc(sizeof(SPPoint*));
if(point == NULL)
{
    return NULL;
}
point->data = (double*) malloc(sizeof(data));
for( int i=0 ; i<dim ; i++)
{
    point->data[i] = data[i];
}
point->dim = dim;
point->index = index;
return point;
}
```

Comment: Wrong size allocated.  `SPPoint* point = malloc(sizeof(SPPoint*));` --> `SPPoint* point = malloc(sizeof *point);`  Same for `point->data = malloc(sizeof *(point->data));`

Comment: Thanks alot, seems to be working now!

Comment: Other issues exist too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `SPPoint* point = malloc(sizeof(SPPoint*));`

should be: `struct SPPoint* point = malloc(sizeof(*point));`

> `point->data = (double*) malloc(sizeof(data));`

should be `point->data = malloc(dim * sizeof(*point->data));`
since you want to allocate `dim` doubles for your point.

Comment: Fixed the first one. Regarding the second one, the data array given to the function is of size dim.

Comment: Won't let me edit :
Fixed the first one. Regarding the second one, the data array given to the function is of size dim. I think point->data = malloc(dim * sizeof(double)); is what you were thinking? Thanks for the answer

Comment: @Bar yes that is it. You have to allocate `dim` doubles

Comment: @Bar notice that even if the givendata  array has size `dim`, the `sizeof` function cannot know it inside the function, because it is given simply as a pointer.

Comment: I see, so what you meant is that sizeof simply gives me the size of a double

Comment: Also, it's not a great idea to cast the return of `malloc()`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: @Bar `sizeof(data)` will give you the size of a pointer (4 or 8 bytes according to platform) and  `sizeof(*data)` will give you the size of a double.

Comment: Regarding the same topic, say I want to change the following code line:
( SPPoint*  parr [n]; )
to a malloc 'form' , like above.
I think this is the correct way and it the program runs but I can't justify it. Can anyone explain?
(      SPPoint**  parr = malloc (n * sizeof(SPPoint*));    )

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Code is mis-allocating in 2 places

```
// Bad
SPPoint* spPointCreate(double* data, int dim, int index){
  SPPoint* point = malloc(sizeof(SPPoint*));  // allocate the size of a pointer
  ...
  point->data = (double*) malloc(sizeof(data)); // allocate the size of a pointer
```

Instead avoid mis-coding the type and allocate to the the size of the de-referenced variable.

Also need to allocate `N` objects.

```
SPPoint* spPointCreate(double* data, int dim, int index){
  size_t N = 1;
  SPPoint* point = malloc(sizeof *point * N);// allocate the size of `*point` * N

  ...
  assert(dim >= 0);
  N = dim;
  point->data = malloc(sizeof *(point->data) * N);
```

BTW, casting the result of `malloc()` not needed.

2nd allocation would benefit with a `NULL` check.  More complicated as `dim` may be 0 and a `malloc()` return of `NULL` in that case is OK.

```
  N = dim;
  point->data = malloc(sizeof *(point->data) * N);
  if (point->data == NULL && N > 0) {
    free(point);
    return NULL;
  }
```